# EAR Deployment in JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, ear

I am getting following error while deploying our EAR to JBoss AS 7.1 as a standalone deployment. Please see the server error log and help me out in what I need to do for it to start functioning correctly. Thank You

```
12:21:47,165 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
12:21:47,167 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
12:21:47,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
12:21:47,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
12:21:47,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
12:21:47,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
12:21:47,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
12:21:47,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
12:21:47,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
12:21:47,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
12:21:47,328 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
12:21:47,467 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
12:21:47,624 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8085
12:21:47,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
12:21:47,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
12:21:47,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
12:21:47,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
12:21:48,018 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.ojdbc14-10_2_0_5_jar (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:/jdbc/DefaultDS] 

12:21:48,036 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Shrisurance.ear"
12:21:54,210 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Shrisurance.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Shrisurance.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "Shrisurance.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to get manifest for deployment "/D:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/Shrisurance.ear/Shrisurance.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:73) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid header field
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:393) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:182) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:52) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.readManifest(VFSUtils.java:216) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.vfs.VFSUtils.getManifest(VFSUtils.java:199) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestAttachmentProcessor.deploy(ManifestAttachmentProcessor.java:69) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 6 more

12:21:54,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
12:21:54,257 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Shrisurance.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"Shrisurance.ear\""}}
12:21:54,258 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 7927ms - Started 136 of 215 services (3 services failed or missing dependencies, 74 services are passive or on-demand)
12:21:54,266 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4)   JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Shrisurance.ear in 7ms
12:21:54,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)              JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service    jboss.deployment.unit."Shrisurance.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in   service jboss.deployment.unit."Shrisurance.ear".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase    STRUCTURE of deployment "Shrisurance.ear"

12:21:54,277 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"Shrisurance.ear\""}}}}
12:22:02,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
```

Comment: Error talks clearly about the missing jars...

Comment: Have you defined a datasource for Oracle?

Comment: Yeah that's the trouble of stacktraces and error logs. There is one perfectly normal error hidden in there and there is one "oh my god the server is erupting" error in there. I guess the latter triggered this question. by the way: ojdbc14 is NOT the driver you want, it is way too old. Pick a more recent one. Perhaps you did, and you forgot to edit the module.xml to point to the new jar.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 :** Looking from log

```
 New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.ojdbc14-10_2_0_5_jar
```

It is found that you are using **ojdbc14** version of jar. It is for **JDK 1.4**. If you are using **JDK 1.4+ version** then use **ojdbc14+ driver**. [Latest Oracle Driver Download Link](http://www.oracleimg.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)

*Modify module.xml ( @ jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\modules\com\oracle\ojdbcXXX\main )*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbcXXX">
  <resources>
   <resource-root path="ojdbcXXX.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
   <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

*Add ojdbcXXX.jar ( @ jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\modules\com\oracle\ojdbcXXX\main )*

*Define Data-source in standalone.xml*

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS">
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID</connection-url>
    <driver>ojdbcXXX</driver>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="ojdbcXXX" module="com.oracle.ojdbcXXX">
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

**Case 2 :** Include other deployments in EAR

JBoss find that dependency spurious. If your EAR contains other deployments like .jar or.war then you can try below :-

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: i have tried to answer check it. May it will solve your problem.